# Unable to show data on data grid view

Tags: c#, database, linq, datagridview

I have problems showing my data inside the data into the data grid view. Can anyone help to solve because they never prompt me any errors while compiling and there are also data inside the database. What comes out inside the data grid view is only the columns and no data inside.

```
private void LoadAllEmpShift()
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            var Viewemp = from ES in Setupctx.employeeshifts
                          join shifthour sh in Setupctx.shifthours on ES.ShiftHourID equals sh.idShiftHours
                         select new
                         {
                             ES.idEmployeeShift,
                             ShiftHour_Start = sh.shiftTiming_start,
                             ShiftHour_Stop = sh.shiftTiming_stop,
                             ES.EmployeeName,
                             ES.StartTime,
                             ES.EndTime,
                             ES.Date
                         };
            dgvShift.DataSource = Viewemp;
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the `DataSource` property, you need to call

```
dgvShift.DataBind();
```

Edit:

I believe the above is for a DataGrid / GridView (in case anyone is using those controls).

**For DataGridView, you need to have a BindingSource.**

Add the `BindingSource` control to your form, then set the `DataSource` property of the `BindingSource` to `Viewemp`

```
dgvBindingSource.DataSource = Viewemp;
dgvShift.DataSource = dgvBindingSource;
```

Comment: Do not have this command .DataBind(). Any more solutions besides that?

Comment: @Philemon - Already updated my answer.  I work too much in web applications :)

Comment: I don't quite understand BindingSource and is there any ways of doing? I try my way of codes and i managed to see the data but I don't know why this can't be used.